# Get FileChannel from AssetManager Android

Tags: java, android, filechannel, android-assetmanager

I want to get a `FileChannel` from the `AssetManager` in Android, is there any way to do this? I want to map some raw custom binary files to some buffers. (If you have a better solution than using the `AssetManager`, please feel free to mention.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

`FileChannel fc = manager.openFd(file).createInputStream().getChannel();`

not sure if it works yet. I will confirm if it does.

Edit:

This only works if the files are uncompressed. You have to use the right file extension or add the -0 flag on aapt. Looking for how to do this on eclipse...